# Why does gas usage differ so much for two very similar functions that just check a condition and set a boolean?

Tags: solidity, gas, bsc, modifiers

I am facing one issue when interacting with my smart contract. Just to add, I have deployed by smart contract in bsc testnet.

It has two similar functions- *enableQuestion* & *disableQuestion*, whose basic functionality is to change the Status of a question. The code is very similar for both, the one difference is that the *disableQuestion* function is calling one extra modifier 'inStatus'. But similar functionality of 'inStatus' is implemented in *enableQuestion* as well.

Now when trying to execute these two functions, here are the gas consumptions. The gas required for *disableQuestion* is insanely high!

```
enableQuestion -> 0.00069382 BNB
disableQuestion -> 0.285 BNB
```

Here is the snippet of the code.

```
modifier inStatus(uint256 _qid, Status _status) {
    require(
        mapQuestions[_qid].status == _status,
        "Operation not valid, invalid question status."
    );
    _;
}

function enableQuestion(uint256 _qid) public onlyOwner validQuestion(_qid) {
    require(
        (mapQuestions[_qid].status == Status.New || mapQuestions[_qid].status == Status.Closed),
        "Operation not valid, invalid question status."
    );
    mapQuestions[_qid].status = Status.Open;
}

function disableQuestion(uint256 _qid) public onlyOwner validQuestion(_qid) inStatus(_qid, Status.Open) {
    mapQuestions[_qid].status = Status.Closed;
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? Also, how can I calculate gas required for each function call ?

UPDATE:

Just saw one more behaviour. The high fee is coming when the condition is failing.

So if I call `disableQuestion(1)` without calling *enableQuestion*, the gas is high. 
But if I call `enableQuestion(1)`, and then call `disableQuestion(1)`, gas is normal.

Comment: What's the solc version? What's `mapQuestions`? From the description is seems the function reverts when the state is invalid and that causes extra gas costs.

Comment: Its deployed in bsc testnet, solidity version is `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;`
mapQuestions is mapping of uint256 and Question struct.

    `mapping(uint256 => Question) public mapQuestions;
    struct Question {
        uint256 questionId;
        uint256 questionCategory;
        ...
    }`

Comment: Also, there seems no reversal as such. Code only checks for the condition, and if it fails, it throws an error.

Comment: Can you provide the transactions hashes for failed and successful? My guess is that a failing require causes the changes in gas consumption.

Comment: I actually never initiated the transaction, as Metamask was showing very high gas fees (0.285 BNB)
But when I actually tried, the gas consumed was not that high (the tx failed btw)
[failed tx (disableQuestion)](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x4efdf26cbf74b1130c4d618ac5b87561d0e432c7d83cbcd409ce9713874ec3a5)
[passed tx (enableQuestion)](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xe4bf3a006c5b96371cf2257acd7e3f5a268aeebf1eccbdb2b0d5c805b133314f)

Comment: From the failed transaction it is clear that disableQuestion requires the `_qid` to be a valid question id and  the question has to be in `Open` status. It will revert otherwise, in that case Metamask uses a high gasLimit 28.5M gas. It makes sense you shouldn't be able to disable a question that doesn't exists or it is in an invalid status.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael for all your efforts. But why does MM calculate such high fees? Anyways the issue is sorted as such, as actual gas consumption is way too less as compared to MM prediction.

Comment: I think MM is doing the right thing since the transaction will revert. It doesn't matter how much money will be spent it will revert anyway and no changes will be recorded in the contract. You shouldn't execute a function that MM says it will revert. Looking at the question 3, perhaps it was in the `New` (0) or `Closed` (2) state and `disableQuestion` fails because it expect it to be at `Open` (1) state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Metamask was predicting very high gas fees. But when transaction was actually executed, it consumed way too less gas.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to smart contracts and blockchain but not to software engineering. Looking at your code would it best to have one function that accepts a boolean for the enable/disable state and then uses a deterministic state machine to only execute valid transitions?

Comment: Agree with your point, one function may suffice usually. But it was done to have clear understanding of what it actually does, as gas fees may vary between these.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense! Thanks.